# Can not run pgAgent as daemon in CentOS 6.6

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I have a server with CentOS 6.6 & postgresql 9.5.

I have successfully setup the pgAgent from source code in postgresql website mentioned, but when I start it, I got error: `Error: Cannot get the official hostname (error 11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`

I start pgagent by this command: `pgagent host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres`
I setup my password in `.pgpass` file, and I can connect to server by using `psql`.